# ansible_become has no effect despite the ability to execute sudo on GCP hosts

Tags: ansible, google-cloud-platform, gcp, ssh, ansible-inventory

Say I want to execute the following command on target hosts (deployed on GCP): `ansible all -a "head -1 /etc/shadow"`.
The command demands the root access. With the default Ansible configuration, I get the following error:

```
host1 | FAILED | rc=1 >>
head: cannot open '/etc/shadow' for reading: Permission deniednon-zero return code
```

Hence, I extended my `ansible.cfg` to include the following:

```
remote_user = gcp_user
ansible_become=yes
ansible_become_method=sudo
ansible_become_user=root
```

Despite these changes, I can't run the command mentioned above. I still get the same error. I am, however, capable of executing the following command: `ansible all -a "sudo cat /etc/shadow"`

Thus, it seems that `become_user=yes` does not take any effect.

Comment: Try without sudo and --become as argument

Answer (score 0):

Running ansible with -vvv will tell you which ansible config you're using

For instance

```
me@mycomputer:~$ ansible -vvv -m setup localhost
ansible 2.10.8
  config file = None
```

shows that I'm not using any config file

chances are pretty OK that is what is happening to you too.  ansible.cfg should be in the current directory or ~/.ansible  (maybe some other places depending on how you installed ansible) you can specify where it is with `ANSIBLE_CONFIG=/path/to/config` in your environment variables

---

The other thing is, the parameters you used in the config file are actually the parameters that go in the playbook, not in the config file

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html

explains where they go in the config file.

When you're running adhoc tasks, you can use them on the commandline (as you wrote) with `-e remote_user=gcp_user -e ansible_become=yes -e ansible_become_method=sudo -e ansible_become_user=root`

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html